# Add search path on compilation

Tags: packages, paths

I need to (for a single compilation) point LaTeX to a (single or multiple additional) directory/es that will be recursively searched for class or package files. This is because I have project specific files which I don't want to put in a (user/system-wide) texmf tree. If LaTeX already chokes not finding the document class I'm doubtful about gettingmy project to work again ...

Comment: in at least unix style shells you can set this on the commandline `TEXINPUTS=/some/path//: pdflatex myfile`   the trailing `//` means include subdirectories and the trailing `:` means include the standard search path at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @David. Unfortunately lualatex still doesn't find the document class ile, although it _is_ below $TEXINPUTS.

Comment: then I think you did something wrong (or you have a very different commandline shell) what operating system and commandline do you use?

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint (basically Ubuntu) and in the normal Terminal (I think that means `bash`).

Comment: then it should work

Comment: OK, on second try it _does_ work, and there is an (usual type of) error much later on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in at least unix style shells you can set this on the commandline

```
TEXINPUTS=/some/path//: pdflatex myfile
```

the trailing `//` means include subdirectories and the trailing `:` means include the standard search path at the end